# classifier works fine but detection fails

Tags: opencv, scikit-learn, computer-vision, svm, object-detection

I am working on a project that detect people and identify whether he is wearing a pair of protection goggles. Now I am using the tradition HOG features to detect human body based on the Dalal's algorithms. My application gave me a confusion matrix like this after I test my data (%80 data used for training and 20% for test) :

[confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dp7T.png).

The result seems to be good but when I use my detector to detect human, It gave me a result like this:

[result of human detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCyKF.png).

The detector even perform worse on other pics

May I ask where is the problem, is it from classifier or my detector?

Sorry that I don not have the privilege to post a image here..

Comment: I am wondering why my post and the answer got a down vote repectively...

Comment: My first guess would be to check if your data is labeled correctly. How is it labeled (amount of people per picture, or exact area's that depict people, or...?)

Comment: @Lexxxxx I simply put pos and neg images in two different folders, and label the pic from pos directory as 1 and the other pics as 0.....However, there are some images in the pos contains more than 1 people....

Comment: Are you positives cropped to mainly show a person? I don't have a lot of experience with computer-vision and human detection but I can imagine that training on full images will learn the classifier the recognize other aspects as positives than just people. Hence why your classifier identifies 4 'people' in your image and still marks them all as correct, resulting in a good confusion matrix.

Comment: Have a look at this people dataset I found http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/

Comment: @Lexxxxx yes! this is where my training set come from. and yes I used the whole picture as the positive should be the source of trouble...I should trim my data....

Comment: This might be the problem. But I can also imagine that a good dataset and algorithm will only find the actual people in photo's as descriptive of 'photo's with people' in them. But cropping definitely wont hurt to point your algorithm in the right direction.

Comment: @Lexxxxx yes~ now I am trying to build my own dataset(shot by myself). I plan to take a few hundred 1:2 pictures with a human standing in front of a white wall.how do you think about this idea?

Comment: This might work but it is often the case that properly labeled real world data is the best data. So for example: if you plan to use this in a certain factory, go there and just take pictures of people working as they normally would and label and crop the data (if this is the way the data would be captured once operational)

Comment: yes, I build a dataset contains 50+photos and it performs well for me, I am planning to add more data into this training set, and Now I am collecting goggles(black color) by taking photos....Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track here. You can improve the results further. Before I get into that, You may get accuracy of around 90 and if you really push hard like 93-94 %(again depending on number of images you have for training and how similar they are with actual use case)

Okay, back to the answer. You have to use Hard negative mining to reduce false positives(i.e detecting a person when there is none). You take all the false positives and add them to the negative class and retrain the classifier. This will help you improve the results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, That's great! I will check it out what is hard negative mining and move forward.

Comment: Hi, man, I found that I have to use the Hard Neg Mining thing...May I ask if there is a exist algorithms or I have to make it by myself....I was so sad....Hahahah